# What is the pythoninc way to replace multiple new line with single and single new line with one space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have a string:

`"2\nOur\nstrategy drives \nsustainably higher profits and margins\n\nStrengthening our hubs is a critical foundation to maximize profitability\n\nDriving revenue improvements from all areas of business\n\nImproving efficiency and productivity \n\nGreater accountability and transparency\n"`

The output should be:

`"2 Our strategy drives sustainably higher profits and margins\nStrengthening our hubs is a critical foundation to maximize profitability\nDriving revenue improvements from all areas of business\nImproving efficiency and productivity \nGreater accountability and transparency "`

Comment: If any of those answers below helped you out, please consider voting on/accepting one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a mapping dictionary:

```
dct = {'\n\n': '\n', '\n': ' '}
```

Using **`re.sub`** (The order of this regex *is* important):

```
re.sub(r'(\n\n|\n)', lambda x: dct[x.group()], s)
```

Output:

```
'2 Our strategy drives  sustainably higher profits and margins\nStrengthening our hubs is a critical foundation to maximize profitability\nDriving revenue improvements from all areas of business\nImproving efficiency and productivity \nGreater accountability and transparency '
```

A bit of explanation to how this works.  Python's regular expression module does not support overlapping matches, so when it matches `\n\n`, it will not also match `\n`, which allows you to do both replacements in a single step.

Comment: Oh, yeah, `re` is nice in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

**A Pythonic solution:**

```
'\n'.join(e.replace('\n', ' ') for e in s.split('\n\n'))
```

First, you split the string where `'\n\n'` occurs, then you substitute `'\n'` for `' '` in each element of the the list, and finally, you join everything together with `'\n'`.

**Another solution**

I would use a temporal helper string that allows me to temporarily replace the double new line, then replace the single newlines with spaces, and then the temporal helper string by newlines:

Let's say your string is `s`:

```
s = "2\nOur\nstrategy drives \nsustainably higher profits and margins\n\nStrengthening our hubs is a critical foundation to maximize profitability\n\nDriving revenue improvements from all areas of business\n\nImproving efficiency and productivity \n\nGreater accountability and transparency\n"

temp = '-\t-'
s = s.replace('\n\n', temp).replace('\n', ' ').replace(temp, '\n')
```

Comment: is it the best pythonic way of doing it... i know tricks, but need a perfect pythonic way of it

Comment: @durjoy, honeslty, I am not sure if this is the most pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Couldn't you just do a regex equivalent of: `s/\s+\n\s+/ /`

Comment: It is the most pythonic way in the universe; you should accept and upvote this answer!

Comment: @StephenRauch, I have limited knowledge on regex :(.

Answer (score 1):

Using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
s = "string\n\n\nwith\n\nmultiple\n\n\nnewlines"
# Replace all multiple newlines with one newline
new_string = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', s)
```